# sum of bar code-locations combination along a timeline

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 tables: 1) "first_day" which contains date, location, barcode(sku) and inventory(quantity). location is a store and sku is an item. There is no duplicates among location-sku combination. date represents only one date 01/01/2020.
2) "transactions" which contains date, location, sku, transaction type, quantity. dates are from 01/02/2020 onwards. transaction types can be "in", "out" and "sale" which i converted to +1, -1, -1 respectively and then multiplied with quantity column to create "total" column.

first_day table

| index | date | location | sku | inventory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01/01/20 | 02 | 2518 | 0 |
| 1 | 01/01/20 | 105 | 425 | 1 |
| 2 | 01/01/20 | 02 | 667 | 1 |

transaction table

| index | date | location | sku | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01/02/20 | 02 | 2518 | 2 |
| 1 | 01/03/20 | 02 | 2518 | -2 |
| 2 | 01/04/20 | 02 | 2518 | 8 |
| 3 | 01/05/20 | 02 | 2518 | -3 |
| 4 | 01/02/20 | 02 | 667 | 12 |
| 5 | 01/03/20 | 02 | 667 | 4 |
| 6 | 01/05/20 | 02 | 667 | -2 |
| 7 | 01/06/20 | 02 | 667 | 3 |

I use first_day table for the unique locations and unique sku. And for the initial quantity of each item from each location.
My mission is to iterate over transaction table and append or subtract the quantity to/from the initial quantity from first_day table.
result table for example:

| index | location | sku | date | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 02 | 2518 | 01/02/20 | 2 # +2 |
| 1 | 02 | 2518 | 01/03/20 | 0 # -2 |
| 2 | 02 | 2518 | 01/04/20 | 8 # +8 |
| 3 | 02 | 2518 | 01/05/20 | 5 # -3 |
| 4 | 02 | 667 | 01/02/20 | 13 # +12 |
| 5 | 02 | 667 | 01/03/20 | 17 # +4 |
| 6 | 02 | 667 | 01/05/20 | 15 # -2 |
| 7 | 02 | 667 | 01/06/20 | 18 # +3 |

My code is not working well, I only get one line that includes the first location from locations, first sku from skus, quantity of zero and date 02/01/2020.

```
first_day = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Inventory_First_day.csv")
master = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Master_skus.csv")
transactions = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Transactions.csv")

transactions['Transaction Type'] = transactions['Transaction Type'].replace({'SALE': -1, 'OUT': -1, 'IN': 1})
transactions['total'] = transactions['Transaction Type'] * transactions['Quantity']

locations = np.unique(first_day['Stock Location Name'])
skus = np.unique(first_day['SKU'])

def skulocation(first_day, transactions, loc, sk):
    
    for location in locations:
        for sku in skus:
            data = first_day[first_day['Stock Location Name'] == location] #filtering for location
            data = data[data['SKU'] == sku]                  #filtering for sku
            if data.empty:                                   #some combintaion not exists in first_day
                data.loc[0,'Date'] = first_day['Date'].iloc[0]     
                data.loc[0,'Stock Location Name'] = location
                data.loc[0,'SKU'] = skus[0]
                data.loc[0,'Inventory'] = 0
            else:
                pass
            
            data2 = transactions[transactions['Stock Location Name'] == location]    #filtering for location
            data2 = data2[data2['SKU'] == sku][['Date', 'Stock Location Name', 'SKU', 'total']] #filtering for sku
            if data2.empty:                                       #some combintaion not exists in transactions
                data2.loc[0,'Date'] = transactions['Date'].iloc[0]
                data2.loc[0,'Stock Location Name'] = location
                data2.loc[0,'SKU'] = sku
                data2.loc[0,'total'] = 0
            else:
                pass
            new_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['location', 'sku','date', 'quantity']) # create new dataframe
            new_frame.loc[0,'quantity'] = data['Inventory'].iloc[0] #initializing with value from first_day 
            for i in range(len(data2)):
                new_frame.loc[i,'location'] = data2['Stock Location Name'].iloc[i]
                new_frame.loc[i, 'sku'] = data2['SKU'].iloc[i]
                new_frame.loc[i,'date'] = data2['Date'].iloc[i]
                new_frame.loc[i, 'quantity'] = new_frame['quantity'].iloc[i] + data2['total'].iloc[i] #add/substract quantity
    return new_frame

new_frame = skulocation(first_day, transactions, locations, skus)
```

Thank you guys

P.S. i edit a little bit the result table.
from the first_day table i need only the quantity of each item at a different location. for example i have chair (item 1) in the following locations: A, B, D, J, Q.
each location has different amount from this chair.
Now i go to the transaction table, and for each locations i follow how the amount of this chair has changed over time.

let's say my starting point is -5.
i have array with values, each place of value represents a date. [3, 1, -6, 8]. at first day i have -5 +3 =-2. then -2 +1= -1, then -1 -6= -7, then -7+8= 1. [-2,-1,-7, 1]

Comment: Please update your data with a coherent sample between df1, df2 and new_frame.

Comment: hi, i edit the coherent samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to concatenate your two dataframes and adding a new index level. Then apply `cumsum` for each group and keep only `transaction` level:

```
out = pd.concat([df1.rename(columns={'inventory': 'total'}), df2], 
                 keys=['inventory', 'transaction'])

out = out.assign(total=out.groupby(['location', 'sku']).cumsum()).loc['transaction']
```

Output:

```
       date  location   sku  total
0  01/02/20         2  2518      2
1  01/03/20         2  2518      0
2  01/04/20         2  2518      8
3  01/05/20         2  2518      5
4  01/02/20         2   667     13
5  01/03/20         2   667     17
6  01/05/20         2   667     15
7  01/06/20         2   667     18
```

Output after `pd.concat`:

```
>>> out
                   date  location   sku  total
inventory   0  01/01/20         2  2518      0  # From 1st dataframe
            1  01/01/20       105   425      1
            2  01/01/20         2   667      1
transaction 0  01/02/20         2  2518      2  # From 2nd dataframe
            1  01/03/20         2  2518     -2
            2  01/04/20         2  2518      8
            3  01/05/20         2  2518     -3
            4  01/02/20         2   667     12
            5  01/03/20         2   667      4
            6  01/05/20         2   667     -2
            7  01/06/20         2   667      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? If not, please add more data. I added some data to the transaction table based on what I understood your ask to be.

```
import io

data1='''index  date    location    sku inventory(quantity)
0   01/01/20    02  2518    0
1   01/01/20    105 425 1'''
df_first_day = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df_first_day

data2='''
index   date    location    sku transaction type    quantity
0   01/02/20    12  2518    sale    14
1   01/02/20    145 4579    in  5
2   01/04/20    02  2518    out 1
3   01/05/20    02  2518    in  20
4   01/06/20    02  2518    in  1
5   01/08/20    02  2518    sale    5
6   01/10/20    02  2518    out 1
7   01/12/20    02  2518    sale    3
'''
df_trx = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df_trx['inventory(quantity)'] = np.where(df_trx['transaction type']=='in', df_trx['quantity'], -df_trx['quantity'])
df_trx

df_adj = pd.concat([df_first_day, df_trx[['index', 'date', 'location', 'sku', 'inventory(quantity)']]]).sort_values(['sku', 'location', 'date'])
df_adj['quantity'] = df_adj.groupby(['sku', 'location'])['inventory(quantity)'].cumsum()
df_adj

   index      date  location   sku  inventory(quantity)  quantity
1      1  01/01/20       105   425                    1         1
0      0  01/01/20         2  2518                    0         0
2      2  01/04/20         2  2518                   -1        -1
3      3  01/05/20         2  2518                   20        19
4      4  01/06/20         2  2518                    1        20
5      5  01/08/20         2  2518                   -5        15
6      6  01/10/20         2  2518                   -1        14
7      7  01/12/20         2  2518                   -3        11
0      0  01/02/20        12  2518                  -14       -14
1      1  01/02/20       145  4579                    5         5
```

**Extra**
If you are looking for just current inventory, you can do something like this

```
df_current_inv = df_adj.groupby(['sku', 'location']).last().reset_index()
```

Comment: you beat me on the post an answer button for few seconds :p

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was specifically the updating of the new_frame variable:

```
def skulocation(df, df2, loc, sk, new_frame = None, **kwargs):
  for location in locations:
    for sku in skus:
      data = df[df['Stock Location Name'] == location] #filtering for location
      data = data[data['SKU'] == sku]                  #filtering for sku
      if data.empty:                                   #some combintaion not exists in first_day
        data.loc[0,'Date'] = df['Date'].iloc[0]     
        data.loc[0,'Stock Location Name'] = location
        data.loc[0,'SKU'] = skus[0]
        data.loc[0,'Inventory'] = 0
      else:
        pass
            
      data2 = df2[df2['Stock Location Name'] == location]    #filtering for location
      data2 = data2[data2['SKU'] == sku][['Date', 'Stock Location Name', 'SKU', 'total']] #filtering for sku
      if data2.empty:                                       #some combintaion not exists in transactions
        data2.loc[0,'Date'] = df2['Date'].iloc[0]
        data2.loc[0,'Stock Location Name'] = location
        data2.loc[0,'SKU'] = sku
        data2.loc[0,'total'] = 0
      else:
        pass
      column_names = ['location', 'sku','date', 'quantity']
  if new_frame is None:
    new_frame = pd.DataFrame({column_names[0]: data2['Stock Location Name'].iloc[0], column_names[1]: data2['SKU'].iloc[0], column_names[2]: data2['Date'].iloc[0], column_names[3]: data2['Inventory'].iloc[0]})
  else:
    i = len(data2)
    new_frame = pd.DataFrame({column_names[0]: data2['Stock Location Name'].iloc[0:i], column_names[1]: data2['SKU'].iloc[0:i], column_names[2]: data2['Date'].iloc[0:i], column_names[3]: str(int(new_frame[column_names[3]].iloc[i]) + int(data2['total'].iloc[i]))})
  return new_frame

new_frame = skulocation(first_day, transactions, locations, skus)
```

Comment: your code has some error.
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index.
What could be wrong?

Comment: I was spotting some of your calculations off of the top of my head since I don't have your dataset to run this code on. I think it was the last column where you want the quantity as the difference between inventory and the current day's quantity, correct? So it should be current day's quantity plus data2's total inventory? I'll adjust my commented code.

Comment: This is not a difference, but I add or subtract the new amount every day

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it; I converted first to integer (assuming it's initially string, if not nbd), added or subtracted (I'm assuming negative numbers are negative), then converted back to string (assuming you want the result in string).

Comment: same error. and you have some mistake here: data2['Inventory'].iloc[0]}) > data2['total'].iloc[0]})
because total column is actualy column that i created. i converted the transaction type column from sale to -1, out to -1 and in to +1, and then multiplied with quantity column. so it gives me the the exact amount of items that arrived at or left the store

Comment: With those changes concerning the calculations and indexing that you listed, does the code work now? As in, does re-defining the new_frame variable as a new dataframe filled with the current index (or indexes) in data2 construct the dataframe in the same way you were intending?

Comment: still not, have the same arror: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index.
I made some changes in my original post. you can see the result that should be

Comment: I just changed the "i + 1" indexing error, also but thanks Paul! sorry if I didn't provide any help.

Comment: still the same problem. i think i have some issue with updating  the new frame i created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237972/discussion-between-paul-and-ori-yarden).